# Fixed Top Navbar with Bootstrap and Angular

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, bootstrap-4

I can't get my fixed top `navbar` working in `Angular`.
My main `app.component` template is: 
`<page-header></page-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

And the bootstrap navbar is included in my page-header:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
            <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="./">Fixed top <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

My router-outlet hast 300% height. What I want to achieve now is that the page-header stays fixed at the top. Is this even possible with Angular and bootstrap 4?

Comment: As your code is, it seems it should, but  if not, set .navbar{position:fixed} in the header stylesheet

Comment: if you use bootStrap 4.0.0, it's NOT navbar-fixed-top, only fixed-top. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: try like this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/navbar-top-fixed/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Fixed it by changing `navbar-fixed-top` to only `fixed-top`